# Combine if statement and for loop such that loop only gets executed once per every execution of if statement in swift

Tags: swift, for-loop, if-statement, command-line

I'm trying to understand swift and therefore try to come up with simple command line games: in this game a player has to guess a secret word within 6 attempts by typing something in the command line, but every time he gets it wrong, a statement prints the number of his wrong attempts:

```
let response = readLine()

if response != "secret word" {
    for n in 1...6 {
        print(n)
    }
}
else {
        print("you are right!")
    }
```

---

Now I know that my code will print all lines once the condition is not true, but I'm looking for a way to only print one item out of the four loop for every if statement consecutively.

Answer (score 0):

I think a while loop works pretty well.  Maybe something like this:

```
print("Welcome to the input game!\n\n\n\n")

var remainingTries = 5

let dictionary = ["apple", "grape", "pear", "banana"]
let secretWord = dictionary.randomElement()

print("Please guess a fruit")

while remainingTries > 0 {
    remainingTries -= 1
    let response = readLine()
    if response == secretWord {
        print("You got it!")
        remainingTries = 0
    } else if remainingTries <= 0 {
        print("Too bad, you lose!")
        remainingTries = 0
    } else {
        print("Incorrect. Tries remaining: \(remainingTries)")
    }
}
```